# Can I trust JavaBean PropertyDescriptor.getName()

Tags: java, security, javabeans, sql-injection

I have a JavaBean class, under my control, that is populated via user-supplied data.  I am using the `Introspector.getBeanInfo(getClass()).getPropertyDescriptors()` chain, and then calling `PropertyDescriptor.getName()` on each of the property descriptors, to construct field names for use in a SQL query.

The question is, does this introduce a potential security vulnerability?  Does the JavaBean spec, for instance, allow user control over the `getName()` method that would allow SQL injection?

Comment: Is this SQL you are writing in a thick client and sending to the database?

Comment: Do you create the column names based on bean class as well? It's difficult to do this in a db independent way - for instance, different db's have different ways of column name quoting, different reserved words, etc.

Comment: Yes, columns are created based on the bean property names, and this is verified ahead of time to succeed.

Comment: @Bryce I see. Why not just a) make sure you generate valid identifiers to begin with and then keep track of them and check input against them? seems a lot saner.

Comment: I certainly could precompute valid column names; my question is more generally about how much work it's safe for me to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't think so; `getName()` has to return a valid property name, and property names can't contain characters dangerous to SQL (',",;, etc.).

However, you should never trust user input, irregardless of the above. You should never put user input directly into SQL queries; you should use [bind variables](http://www.akadia.com/services/ora_bind_variables.html) and, in Java, [prepared statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html). At the very least, you should [escape](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html) all user input for [SQL](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeSql(java.lang.String)) before it gets anywhere near your database.

Comment: Sure but if someone really tore open the program, couldn't they inject all kinds of things with AOP?

Comment: Prepared statements in Java cannot parameterize column names.

Comment: @Bryce, are you using the property name for table generation, e.g. `CREATE` statements? Or are you using them to select fields from existing, known tables?

Comment: @F.StephenQ they are generating INSERT statements for known tables.

Comment: @Bryce Then maybe you should just check the property names against your known column names.

Comment: Yo̶u̶ ̶m̶i̶g̶h̶t̶ ̶w̶a̶n̶t̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶c̶o̶n̶s̶i̶d̶e̶r̶ ̶v̶a̶l̶i̶d̶a̶t̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶u̶s̶e̶r̶-̶p̶r̶o̶v̶i̶d̶e̶d̶ ̶n̶a̶m̶e̶s̶ ̶a̶g̶a̶i̶n̶s̶t̶ ̶y̶o̶u̶r̶ ̶l̶i̶s̶t̶ ̶o̶f̶ ̶k̶n̶o̶w̶n̶ ̶c̶o̶l̶u̶m̶n̶ ̶n̶a̶m̶e̶s̶ ̶b̶e̶f̶o̶r̶e̶ ̶a̶l̶l̶o̶w̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶m̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶b̶e̶ ̶i̶n̶s̶e̶r̶t̶e̶d̶ ̶i̶n̶t̶o̶ ̶y̶o̶u̶r̶ ̶q̶u̶e̶r̶y̶. @pvg ++

Comment: Can one actually make the assumption that getName() returns a valid property name?  Is that guaranteed by the spec?

Comment: By the spec, `getName()` must return the "programmatic" name for the specified property, which is the same name specified in the `get<name>()` and `set<name()` methods. I can't speak to any specific implementation, but a `getName()` implementation that followed the spec would not return any Java reserved characters, which happens to overlap with the set of SQL reserved characters.

Comment: `PropertyDescriptor`s can be custom and provided by, say, a `BeanInfo` implementation. This could in theory be used to return bad names from `getName`. Or you could use it yourself to ensure your `getName` returns exactly what you want. But that seems more work and more convoluted than just having your class provide the column names to begin with.

Answer (score -1):

When you say

> allow user control over the getName()

That makes me suspect that this is client side SQL your application is writing? Certainly that should not be ever trusted and run directly on your database. [Further discussion is readily available](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/180014/206003)

If it is server side, I can't imagine your users being able to change property names, unless you are mapping something like JSON, and a library like `GSON` allows invalid POJO property names in some half deserialized state.

In any case, you could map these Java objects over to ORM tooling and avoid the SQL injection issues, if that fits with our architecture. Assuming again, this is server side.

Comment: The SQL is being constructed server-side; the issue is that the JavaBean is being constructed based on user input.  "unless you are mapping something like JSON, and a library like GSON allows invalid POJO property names in some half deserialized state" is exactly the sort of thing I'm worried about, although it seems unlikely.  Serialization corner cases that allow getName to be overridden are another thing I'm curious about.